# Find the height of the box.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A box contains 150 candles. It has a width that is five times the height of the box and a length that is thrice the width of the box. The volume of each candle is 1 $in^3$. Find the height of the box.

Please help me with this question. I know the volume of the box would be 150 $in^3$, but I'm not sure how to find the height. Thank you!

Comment: Are you meant to assume that the candles fill the box perfectly?  Candles are usually cylinders....

Answer (score 1):

We assume the candles are cylinders.  Clearly the candles are packed in a $3 \times 5$ grid from the problem statement.  They must then stacked $10$ high to get the count.  If the height of the box is $h$, each candle then fits in an $h \times h \times h/10$ box.  If we assume the candles are cylinders, they have a volume of $\pi (\frac h2)^2 \frac h{10}=\frac {\pi h^3}{20}=1$, so $h=\sqrt[3]{\frac {20}\pi}$

Answer (score 0):

If the height is $h$, then the width is $5h$, which means that the length is $3*5h=15h$. Multiplying these, we obtain:

$$Vol = l*w*h = (15h)(5h)(h) = 75h^3$$

Since we know the volume should be $150$, we can write:

$$150=75h^3$$,

which leads to:

$$h^3=2$$.

Thus, the height of the box is $\sqrt[3]{2}\,in.$, or about $1.25992\,in.$, and you can find the width and length by multiplying by $5$ and $15$, respectively.

Comment: We do not know the volume is $150$, in fact we know (assuming the candles are cylinders) that it is not.

Comment: Well, those last couple of equal signs can be replaced with inequalities, then. From the way the problem was stated, I was assuming the volume of the box is completely occupied by candles, which could happen if the candles are rectangular prisms, or any of a variety of other shapes.

Comment: Actually dealing with the way cylinders pack in 3 dimensions seems that it would make the problem considerably harder. We don't know the dimensions of each candle.

Comment: I think we have to assume the candles are packed $1 \times 3 \times 5$ in the box.  Given that $3,5$ are small I suspect that is optimal.  Then each candle is in a $1\times 1 \times 1$ cube, so we can find the best cylinder that fits that volume.  We have certainly not proved this optimal, but I would bet big money that the problem poser was thinking this way.

Comment: Huh. I would take that bet. Candles may typically be cylinders, but cylinders with height equal to their diameter would be highly atypical. (Birthday candles would be taller than they are wide, and votives tend to be the opposite.) I'm leery of assuming much that isn't stated. It's easier for me to assume that the problem poser didn't think it through very carefully. Hard to say.

Comment: They are still cylindrical, and you can't pack cylinders with full density. You are assuming cubical candles-would you rather assume that or cylinders with the same height and diameter?

Comment: I wouldn't assume cylinders, unless the problem said cylinders, and I'm not assuming cubes. I'm just assuming that the space is filled, which does not imply cubes. If we assume the space isn't filled, then there's not enough information to do the problem, unless we assume more stuff.

Comment: Even if you assume that the candles are rectangular boxes, there's a problem.  The count doesn't work!  If N is the number of candles packed along a length, and M the number packed along a width, then surely the assumptions require that N = 3M, no?  But then we must have 150 = $3M^2$ or 50 = $M^2$ and that just isn't an integer.

Comment: The assumptions require no such thing. We know nothing about the dimensions of the candles. All we really know is that this is a poorly written problem.

Comment: I didn't come up with this problem. I can't help that it was "poorly written". It was taken out of a textbook. I just need help answering the problem.

Comment: @Will, no I didn't figure you wrote it. I hope that one of the answers here is helpful. Do we have any way of knowing if one of them is correct?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs The answer is h = 0.67. That doesn't sound correct to me but it's supposed to be the answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird, because it puts the volume of the box at around 22.5 cubic inches, which shouldn't be enough to hold all those candles.